# MII/GMII switch for 10/100 Mbps vs 1Gbps

Tags: ethernet, mii

The lack of search results I've got so far suggests that I have a fundamental misconception here, but: for a PHY with a MII/GMII interface such as the [KSZ9031MNX](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/00002096E.pdf), how does the MAC decide whether to use MII or GMII signaling?

Should I wait for the PHY to signal that autonegotiation is complete, then read PHY status registers and reconfigure accordingly, or is there a more direct method?